# how do i move file to a new folder

Tags: python, image-processing, shutil

i'm new in python, so i want to scan an overexposure images in a folder. and then those overexposure images move to a new folder.

so this is the code what i've tried

```
import cv2
import os
import shutil 
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

os.chdir("./sample)
for file in glob.glob("*jpg)
    frame = cv2.imread(file)
    print(frame)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    image_value2 = bright_pixel/total_pixel >dark_thres
    if image_value2:
       print("{} - Face is overexposed!".format(file))
       am = Image.fromarray(frame)
       am.save("./reject/{}.jpg".format(file))
```

so i want to move to the "reject" folder
i skip the code to the main problem, so when i run that code it show this error.

```
File "tes_expo.py", line 52
am = Image.fromarray(frame)
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

am i done something wrong? i would appreciate every answer. thanks in advance !

Comment: TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: Don't mix TABs and Spaces in your indentations. Either use TABS or Spaces.

Comment: some editors/IDEs have function "convert tabs to 4 spaces" somewhere in menu and/or "automatically convert tabs to 4 spaces when you save" somewhere in settings. It can resolve this problem.

Comment: i still don't get what u just sayin, can u explain in easier way? @AkshayNevrekar

Comment: What I am saying is at some places you have used SPACES(4 spaces) and at some places you have used TAB for **indentations** in your code. Be consistent and either you use `4 SPACES` or `TAB` throughout your code. If you mix them while coding it might throw the error you are getting